# WPF Custom Data grid with button inside cell

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, custom-controls

In WPF xaml, I would like to make a custom data grid with button in cell. I want to create button in the last column as shown in below figure.

[Custom data grid : Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtRUy.png)

Here while pressing Add button some operation will happen and data will be added to that cell and button should be shown in next column.

I could add column with button using below code. But I don't know how add this button in the last column of of each row.

```
          <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Button Height="30" Width="30"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: One way is to add buttons in the cells wherever it is needed and handle the Visibility of the buttons.

Comment: Means I should add button dynamically. Some times cell can contain text some times button. For that, all columns should be a template column right?

Comment: Yes, it should be template column. You can directly add the buttons in the xaml and define a property for the visibility of the button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Cutsom DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319043/wpf-cutsom-datagrid)

Comment: This is the answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/35186/wpf-custom-data-grid-with-button.html. Thank you all